# Are corporations free market on the outside and communist dictatorships on the inside?

Tags: markets, theory-of-the-firm

[See why we hate working for big companies](https://medium.com/s/story/why-we-hate-working-for-big-companies-9e6c787a32ac) 
What do you think of the proposition that Modern capitalism raises the flag of the free market while pitting centrally planned organisations against each other?

Could firms introduce a free market internally? What would be the benefits and problems?

Comment: A planned organisation and a communist dictatorship is not the same thing, please remove the hyperbole. You could also remove the entire first paragraph, it is essentially meaningless, seeking opinion.